# checking if a key in one of the dictionaries in python

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I have a javascript code:

```
const isValid = function (area, row, col, num) {
  if (area[num] || row[num] || col[num]) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

I am trying to write this in python but I could not figure out.

```
def is_valid(area, row,col,num):
     if (num in area) or (num in row) or (num in col):
         return False
     else:
         return True
```

this did not work. then I tried this:

```
   def is_valid(area, row,col,num):
      if num in area:
         return False
      elif num in row:
         return False
      elif num in col:
          return False
      else:
         return True
```

this did not work neither. because both is_valid always returns False

```
box={"1":True,"5":True}
row={"6":True,"8":True}
col={"3":True,"7":True}

 for num in range(9)
```

Comment: What is your input?

Comment: @Selcuk box, row and col are objects and I printed them. and num is a stringified number

Comment: What are the contents of area, row, col - can you post some example?

Answer (score 0):

Your `num` is an integer while your keys are strings. Try

```
def is_valid(area, row,col,num):
    return all(str(num) not in d for d in (area, col, row))
```

or

```
def is_valid(area, row,col,num):
    return str(num) not in dict(**area, **row, **col)
```